# Characteristic polynomial and matrix over finite field

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider the finite field $\mathbb{F}_2$ and all polynomial of degree $n$ over the finite field. So there are $2^{n+1}-1$ number of possible *non-zero* polynomials. It is needless to mention that there are $2^{n^2}$ number of all possible matrices over $\mathbb{F}_2$.

For each of the polynomial can we find the matrix (over the finite field) whose characteristic polynomial is the polynomial.

If yes, How?

Comment: Google "Companion matrix"